# In BLE pairing procedures, which channel is used for communication?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm working at electronics company.

And I was wondering which channel is used until two BLE devices are paired?

Does it use advertisement channel to exchange required information to pair? Or once advertisement is end and Central request to pair and then change the channel to data channels and also use channel hop?

Please tell me~~
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, setting up the connection is done on the  advertizing channels (which are only 3 if I remember correctly).

After everything is set up and negotiated, it is switched to the data channels (37 in total) which follows a pseudo random channel hopping sequence.

Pairing happens on the data channels.

Comment: Minor correction - there are 40 channels in total, 3 of which are advertising channels, and 37 are data channels where the pairing happens as you said. More info on pairing can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862560/should-one-create-a-bond-with-a-bluetooth-le-device/42916081#42916081